# Email Error in Phalcon

Tags: php, email, url, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I am new user of phalcon php I face a problem when try to send email using Phalcon Php Screen Shot of Error is Given Below

[image: error image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: And where is code ?

Comment: A file with the name mail.php is located in app/library i copy paste code here?

Answer (score 0):

Phalcon does not have an email system. You must be using an external library which you should ask properly with the right tags.

Proposing to close

Comment: The project is already build by some other developer i just start working on it and phalcon is new for me i trying my best for removing this error but i am unable to do it.